# Creating object in Python

Tags: python

Is there any differences between these to declare an object?

```
class MyStuff(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.tangerine = "And now a thousand years between"
```

and

```
class MyStuff:

def __init__(self):
    self.tangerine = "And now a thousand years between"
```

Comment: Read the data model docs, specifically the __init__ method is relevant here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x, there's no difference as it only has new-style classes... if you're using Python 2.x, then the first example results in a new-style class and the second an old-style class... that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. At least, there's a difference in Python 2.

`class MyStuff:` creates an old-style class,

`class MyStuff(object):` creates a new-style class.

In Python 3, all classes are new-style.

From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

> Classes and instances come in two flavors: old-style (or classic) and
>   new-style.
>
> Up to Python 2.1 the concept of class was unrelated to the concept of
>   type, and old-style classes were the only flavor available. For an
>   old-style class, the statement `x.__class__` provides the class of `x`,
>   but `type(x)` is always `<type 'instance'>`. This reflects the fact that
>   all old-style instances, independent of their class, are implemented
>   with a single built-in type, called instance.
>
> New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2 to unify the concepts
>   of class and type. A new-style class is simply a user-defined type, no
>   more, no less. If `x` is an instance of a new-style class, then `type(x)`
>   is typically the same as `x.__class__` (although this is not guaranteed
>   – a new-style class instance is permitted to override the value
>   returned for `x.__class__`).
>
> The major motivation for introducing new-style classes is to provide a
>   unified object model with a full meta-model. It also has a number of
>   practical benefits, like the ability to subclass most built-in types,
>   or the introduction of “descriptors”, which enable computed
>   properties.
>
> For compatibility reasons, classes are still old-style by default.
>   New-style classes are created by specifying another new-style class
>   (i.e. a type) as a parent class, or the “top-level type” object if no
>   other parent is needed. The behaviour of new-style classes differs
>   from that of old-style classes in a number of important details in
>   addition to what type() returns. Some of these changes are fundamental
>   to the new object model, like the way special methods are invoked.
>   Others are “fixes” that could not be implemented before for
>   compatibility concerns, like the method resolution order in case of
>   multiple inheritance.
>
> While this manual aims to provide comprehensive coverage of Python’s
>   class mechanics, it may still be lacking in some areas when it comes
>   to its coverage of new-style classes. Please see
>   https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/ for sources of additional
>   information.
>
> Old-style classes are removed in Python 3, leaving only new-style
>   classes.